# Delete documents in Elasticsearch with Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I created an index

```
self.elasticsearch.indices.create(index="cards_index")
```

inserted data

```
for index in range(100):
   document = {"question": question, "answer": answer,
                "creation_time": 1234567890,
                "interval_time": 1234567890, "box_id": 1}
   self.elasticsearch.index(index="cards_index",
                id=str(index), body=document)
```

and tried to delete all data

```
for index in range(100):
   self.elasticsearch.delete(index="cards_index",
                id=str(index))
```

but when I get all data I still found these documents although they should be deleted. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does it eventually get deleted or it is not getting deleted at all?

Comment: It is not getting deleted at all. I use
res = self.elasticsearch.search(index="cards_index", size=10000, body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
to validate that the deletion was successful (or not like in my case).

Comment: Can you print the output of the delete request

Comment: I found out that the insert of data wasn't complete when the data should be deleted. When I use time.sleep(2) before I delete all data it works as I expected it. Now my question is: What can I do so that the delete operation waits for the insert operation to be completed?